# Optimising WP_Query with ACF Fields

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, query-posts, optimization

I am wondering if it's still possible to optimise the `WP_Query` or also if there's another way of doing it. I have the `post` type and a custom post type called `case-study` which gets displayed on the website as a result in `search.php`. I have read the documentation, have done a simple test and confirm it can work, but it's a bit of a messy solution. The solution basically involves doing a `wp_query` for post and another `wp_query` for the ctp and merging.

Query 1

```
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => array(
                        'case-studies'
                    ),
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'meta_key' => 'header_title', //ACF Test
                    'meta_value' => $s,
                    'fields' => 'ids'
                );
```

Query 2

```
                $args2 = array(
                    's' => $s,
                    'post_type' => array(
                        'post'
                    ),
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'fields' => 'ids'
                );
```

Merge

```
                $cs_query = get_posts( array_merge( $defaults, $args  ) );
                $post_query = get_posts( array_merge( $defaults, $args2 ) );
                $post_ids = array_merge ( $cs_query, $post_query ); 

                $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
                    'post_type' =>  array(
                        'case-studies',
                        'post'
                    ),
                    'post__in'  => $post_ids,
                    'orderby'   => 'post__in', 
                    'order'     => 'ASC' 
                ));
```

I am wondering if there's a way to optimise this.

Comment: You haven't really said what you're actually trying to do. If you just want a post type to appear in search results then all you need to do is make sure [`exclude_from_search`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) is `false` when you register the post type.

Comment: Oops - good point.

Basically I need results from both `post` and `case-studies` but with `case-studies` , it will only include results where a field is not empty. My initial thought to solve this was through the solution above, but 2 `get_posts` + a `wp_query` is not nice.